# Inserting rows, selecting range and setting the background color based on another sheet's data in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am stuck at a point with Google apps script. Please help me out

I have a set of rows in `Sheet1` and based on each row in a table in `Sheet1` I am inserting 13 set of rows in `Sheet2` corresponding to each row populated in the table in `Sheet1`

When `J11` is populated in`Sheet1` and the button linked to apps script function executes, the following should happen in `Sheet2`

1. Insert 13 rows starting from row 43
2. The cell D43 should update with a concatenated string from `Sheet1` from the first row in the table, which here is `B11, H111 and J11`
3. The range `D43:F43` should set color to a grey background
4. The range `H43:I55` should set color to a grey background(13 rows and 2 columns)
5. The range `K43:P55` should set color to a grey background(13 rows and 6 columns)
6. The range `R43:Y55` should set color to a grey background(13 rows and 8 columns)
7. The range `AA43:AH55` should set color to a grey background(13 rows and 8 columns)

I wrote the code for Step1 to Step3 with the below code, but not able to figure out how to go ahead with rest of the steps

```
function addPricingRows() {
  d1= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Product_Details = d1.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var Product_Pricing = d1.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  
  var offset_from1 = Product_Pricing.getRange("D43")
  var check = Product_Details.getRange("J11").isBlank();
  if(!check){
  Product_Pricing.insertRowsAfter(42,13);
  
  var a= Product_Details.getRange("B11").getValue();
  var b= Product_Details.getRange("H11").getValue();
  var c= Product_Details.getRange("J11").getValue();
  Product_Pricing.getRange("D43").setValue(a+"-"+b+"-"+c);
  var range1 = Product_Pricing.getRange("D43:F43");
  const range2 = offset_from1.offset(0,4).getA1Notation();
  range1.setBackground("#e6e6e6");
  range2.setBackground("#e6e6e6");

  }
  else{
    Product_Pricing.deleteRows(43,13)
  }
}
```

Please help me achieve this, here is the link to spreadsheet for reference- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/180iMihBq9-Gep9Em6v570pshPRNgsruaboFv5e4XHes/edit#gid=13131281

Thanks in advance

Comment: the ```setBackground``` function is built into google apps script. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor) is a link to it specifically.

Comment: How can I select the ranges in step 4 to 7 with a reference to cell D43, I I can do that I can offset and get the ranges and change the background color instead of hard coding it

Comment: I'm sorry, your question is confusing me, what are you asking for again?

Comment: In Steps 4 to 7 in my question, I am trying to color the ranges, instead of setting those ranges manually, Howe can I get those ranges by  making the cell D43 as  as reference cell

Comment: If you're asking how to get that range as a reference call, then it should just be ```ss.getRange('D43:F43')``` with sheet being your spreadsheet obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you're trying to set a specific range of cells to a certain color, it should just be `sheet.getRange('D43:F43').setBackground('gray')`, where sheet is the name of a specific sheet on your spreadsheet. You can also use a hex color in place of just `'gray'`. For example: #ffffff is just white.